# Heirarchical Sub-Menu - ios?

Tags: iphone

how can I populate an array of product and category on table in ios using xcode4.5 storyboard. I am using a singleView project can you please tell me the steps.
i found some codes but they used .xib file and i don't know how to add a .xib file in my project.Does It requires the .xib file or can be done without .xib file?

example:

icecreame

```
    strawbwry  10
    vanila     29
```

cake

```
   strawbwry-cake  10
   vanila -cake    29
   pineApple -cake    29
   pineApple -cake    29
```

cake-2

```
   strawbwry-cake  10
    vanila -cake    29
    pineApple -cake    29
    pineApple -cake    29
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://github.com/TheAKDev/iOS-Tree-Component
It's example how to make drop-down tables from UITableView

Answer (score 0):

Use a sectioned Tableview.

Use

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 3; //Will return 3 sections (=categories)
}
```

for each category and

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if(section==0){ //Icecream
        return 2; //You will have 2 products for ice cream
    }else if(section==1){
        return 4; //You will have 4 products for cake.
    }
}
```

In

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

do it like this:

```
if(indexPath.section==0){
    //Icecream
    //Create your cell and return it.
}else if(indexPath.section==1){
    //Cake
    //Again, create your instance of UITableViewCell and return it.
}
```

Comment: How can we collapse and expand the main level on clicking?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you talking about "collapsing" the whole section after one of its cells have been selected?

Comment: No I am talking about collapsing or expanding a section when the section has been clicked .For example when I click on ice cream then strawberry and vanilla disappear.When I click it again the strawberry and vanilla appear again.

Comment: Well, you can't click or tap a section just that easily. A section is just a group of Tableview cells. But what you could do is, for example, use the tableview's `viewForHeaderInSection`-method to create some sort of button above the each section and if the button is pressed, you could just remove the cells of that particular section and add them again after the button was tapped again.

Comment: I just found something that might help you. Take a look at this: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/jkexpandtableview